# getJSON not working at windows phone 8.1

Tags: jquery, cordova, windows-phone, intel-xdk

I'm using Intel XDK to develop cross-platform apps, and I already deployed it at Android and everything is ok. But when I try at Windows Phone 8.1 it does not work the method getJSON from JQuery API. I'm using the latest version of Intel XDK, so I'm not sure wich Cordova and JQuery version I'm using. Here is the code i'm trying and worked at Android(this is me testing, i already can read webservices in Android).

```
//$support.cors = true; ALREADY TRYED IT AND DIDN'T WORK
//$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; ALREADY TRYED IT AND DIDN'T WORK
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) 
{

    alert( "getJSON worked." );

}).fail( function( jqxhr, textStatus, error )
{

    alert( textStatus + " " + error );

});
```

This code gives me the alert: "error " and nothing else. Can anyone give me a light? Thanks.

Comment: are you sure the url is correct and you get json back?

Comment: Yes, I'm. Im using the same URL in Android and it is fine.

Comment: I'd recommend debugging it by using a regular "get", either with jQuery or the old fashioned way with XMLHttpRequest.  Then check the result you get, or if you get an error check that.  As you have it, I can't tell if it's the JSON parser that has an error or if the response didn't work.

Comment: The problem is with the method $.getJSON from jQuery, I tried with the ajax method and it worked.